# php foreach over an array and assignment of this array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I want to add a value to an array while foreaching it :

```
foreach ($array as $cell) {
    if ($cell["type"] == "type_list") {
        $cell["list"] = $anObject;
        error_log(print_r($cell, TRUE), 0);
}
error_log(print_r($array, TRUE), 0);
```

The first printr is ok but the object added disapear when I leave the loop ant print the array.

I guess this is a normal behaviour, what is the best way to work around this "feature" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php insert value into array of arrays using foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491704/php-insert-value-into-array-of-arrays-using-foreach)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just call `$cell` by reference like this:

```
foreach($array as &$cell) {...}
```

And it should retain the value. [Passing by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 4):

When you iterate over the array, `$cell` is a copy of the value, not a reference so changing it will not effect the value in the array.

You should either use `&` to make the `$cell` a reference:

```
foreach ($array as &$cell) {
    if ($cell["type"] == "type_list") {
        $cell["list"] = $anObject;
        error_log(print_r($cell, TRUE), 0);
}
error_log(print_r($array, TRUE), 0);
```

Or access the array items directly using an index.

```
foreach ($array as $i => $cell) {
    if ($array[$i]["type"] == "type_list") {
        $array[$i]["list"] = $anObject;
        error_log(print_r($array[$i], TRUE), 0);
}
error_log(print_r($array, TRUE), 0);
```