# php insert value into array of arrays using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

I have a pretty basic question but I am stuck. I am pretty new to php and I have an array like this:

```
$array = array(
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => array('key1' => 'val1','key2' => 'val2'),
    'three' => array('key1' => 'val1','key2' => 'val2'),
    'four' => array('key1' => 'val1','key2' => 'val2')
);
```

and for each of the arrays in the array (that is, 'two, 'three', and 'four'), I want to insert 'key3' => 'val3' into those arrays.

I tried this:

```
foreach($array as $item) {
    if (gettype($item) == "array") {
        $item['key3'] = 'val3';
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work, and I'm not sure why. Using various print_r's all over the place, it seems to insert 'key3' => 'val3' into $item if I print it out in the loop, but the original array seems unchanged. I also tried a regular for loop but that didn't work either.

Comment: Do the key and its value are equals for each sub-array?

Comment: curious why you didn't just do `foreach ($array as $item_key => $item) { $array[$item_key]['key3'] = 'val3'; } `

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works with a copy of `$item`, so you cannot modify your original array inside the `foreach`. One way to work around this is to use the `&` operator.

```
foreach($array as &$item) {
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $item['key3'] = 'val3';
    }
}
```

Another, more elegant way would be to use [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php):

```
array_walk($array, function (&$v, $k) { 
    if (is_array($v)) {
        $v['key3'] = 'val3';
    }
});
```

This example will work from PHP 5.3, where Closures were introduced.

Comment: $item is only generated for the loop . You mean `&$array['key3'] = 'val3';` !

Comment: @moskito-x I certainly mean what I wrote. That's the point of it. Check the `foreach` manual page I linked.

Comment: To change $item is useless. Will be always overwritten by the next loop.

Comment: But `As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop may lead to unexpected behavior.` therefore you have to unset the reference . `unset($item);` // break the reference with the last element. [structures.foreach](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The first solution worked fine but the second solution didn't seem to work, it's obvious I need to get a little better at php. Can I just stick that & symbol anywhere? Wow that would change things. Also, thanks for the tip on using unset($item), not knowing that would have eventually sunk me somewhere down the line for sure!

Comment: @BenjaminThvedt Fixed the second one. Don't overuse the `&` operator, most of the time there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a function to check whether a variable is an array or not: `is_array()`. Use this:

```
if (is_array($item)) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

while looping with foreach use key like :

```
foreach($array as $key => $item){

    $array[$key]['newElement'] = "newValue";

}
```

Comment: While not the answer to the question, this helped me better understand the relationship between the `$key` word and the `$item`.