# PHP foreach insert array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays, and I am trying to foreach loop through and insert new item into the sub arrays.

take a look below

```
            $newarray = array(
                    array("id"=>1,"quantity"=>2),
                    array("id"=>1,"quantity"=>2),
                    array("id"=>1,"quantity"=>2),
           );

           foreach($newarray as $item){
                $item["total"] = 9;
            }
           echo "<br>";
           print_r($newarray);
```

The result just give me the original array without the new "total". Why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491704/php-insert-value-into-array-of-arrays-using-foreach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$item` is not a reference of `$newarray[$loop_index]`:

```
foreach($newarray as $loop_index => $item){
    $newarray[$loop_index]["total"] = 9;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Will accept it after 10 minute timer.

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach()` statement gives `$item` as an array: Not as the real value (consuming array). That meaning it can be read but not changed unless you then overwrite the consuming array.

You could use the `for()` and loop through like this: [see demo](https://3v4l.org/rCWhI).

Note: This goes all the way back to scopes, you should look into that.